# add Information(text or csv) to image in android

Tags: android, csv, tags, photo

I am trying to add few things like names, places to images. The idea is to have them sorted according to name or place when the users uses it.

I have the code working to take pictures and save it to the Phone's memory.

How can i add this Tag of information in my code?

Or even how can i add metadata to an image??

Comment: could you be more clear on what you just said?

Comment: I have pictures taken with my app. I want to add feature to the picture taken to let the user tag the place the photo was taken or the names of the people in it. After tagging i want to let users sort their gallery using the tags. Hope this is clear---@user2247689

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what i was looking for we can add extra information to an image using [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, what you could do is create a database and have in three fields:

1. Names
2. Places
3. Image path

Use a `GridView` to show the images in your app(and load them images from the database). On `GridView` `ItemClick` you could prompt the user to add in tags into the image, later on you could use these fields to sort the image in you application.

Hope this helps.